# What is the difference between these sql wildcards?

Tags: sql

Below is my basic query.

```
SELECT count(distinct o_custkey) FROM orders
WHERE
    o_comment LIKE '% word %'
```

I want to understand the difference between `'% word %'`, `'%word%'`, and `' % word % '`.

Comment: space character before/after, or not.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard is always the same.  It is `%`.  This matches any string of characters in `o_comment`, including an empty string.  So `%word%` matches all of the following:  `'word'`, ' word '`,` '123445345345word242424'`.

The rest of the characters need to match exactly.  So as explained:

- `'% word %'` matches any string that has "word" with spaces before and after.
- `'%word%'` matches any string that has "word" at all in the string.
- `' % word % '` matches any string that starts and ends with a space.  And then has "word" surrounded by spaces.  Note that these are "different" spaces, so this matches `'  word  '` (two spaces at the beginning and end) but not `' word '` (one space).

Answer (score 0):

The `%` wildcard matches anything, including the empty string. So

1. `%word%`  matches anything that contains `word`. Eg `word`, `foowordbar`, `fooword`, `wordbar`, `foo word bar` ..., but not something like `wor`, `foowor`, `fooworbard`
2. `% word %` matches anything that contains  `word` , ie with enclosing spaces, Eg  `word` , `foo word bar`,  `word foo`, `bar word`  , but not `fooword`  ,  `wordbar` or  `wor d`
3. `% word %`  matches any string, that starts and ends with a space   and contains  `word`  enclosed in spaces (like 2). But because you have a space before and after the wildcard  `word`  (ie only a single space in the beginning and the end of the string) is not matched, but   `word`   (ie two spaces in the beginning and the end) is.